# English version on Dynkin's 1963 paper on stopping

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, translation

I am looking for an English version of the following paper:
[Е. Б. Дынкин, Оптимальный выбор момента остановки марковского процесса, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 150, 238-240 (1963)](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/90266b686b9cdc78a7808142cc8e51da/dan27932.pdf).

Comment: Zentralblatt (http://zbmath.org) gives references to translations of most papers, if available. Zentralblatt is free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynkin, E. B.
The optimum choice of the instant for stopping a Markov process. (English. Russian original) Zbl 0242.60018
Sov. Math., Dokl. 4, 627-629 (1963); translation from Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 150, 238-240 (1963).

Answer (score 3):

According to https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0242.60018 , it was translated in *Soviet Mathematics. Doklady* (https://zbmath.org/serials/?q=se%3A00000717), but I doubt it was digitised, so you just need to demand a hardcopy from the library of a university near you (for instance, libraries in Paris seem to have it: https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/bibli/catalogue/perio/execAffiche.php?ref=42).

Comment: very odd, seems to be a significant paper..

Answer (score 0):

I found an English translation in

https://bookstore.ams.org/cworks-14